# Basic Pointer Arithmetic that has me stumped

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I'm working on a problem that uses pointer arithmetic and I have found this small snippet of code that works. I don't understand exactly what it's doing though. To me it looks like it is assigning the address of buffer + the value of ix3 to the array element a[i]. I don't know why that would be relevant to my program though. Can someone please tell me exactly what is happening in this loop?

```
int *buffer=new int[5*3];

for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    a[i] = buffer+i*3;
```

Comment: In what way does it "work" ? What's so unusual ?

Comment: You should add the type of the variable a. It should be array of pointer to an integer. This in mind, it may help to understand more of the program. If the type of a is not something like an array of interger pointers, you may show more of the code.

Comment: @harper a is defined in the variables list as int** a; and will serve as a 2D array later in the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

```
buffer+i*3
```

is identical to

```
&buffer[i*3]
```

so your assumption is correct, and I hope that `a[]` is an array of pointers.

Note that pointer arithmetic like `buffer+k` does *not* take the address value contained in `buffer` and add k to it: instead, it's equal to the value of `&buffer[k]`, which should equal the address value contained in buffer + k * sizeof(the type being pointed to by buffer ).

Comment: Yes a is defined as int** a; in my variables list and acts as a 2D array later in the program. I want to write all the values of a into a contiguous block of memory (buffer). This was the only line of code I didn't understand in the solution I seen. I'm not 100% sure how this works though

Comment: The values `a` points to are already in a contiguous block of memory, the one allocated with `new`.

Comment: No, I meant that I hope that the type of a is an array of pointers, as adohertyd clarified.

Answer (score 2):

It does exactly what you said. The array `a` (whose definiton you didn't show) probably has the type `int* [5]`.

The purpose of this is to enable normal double-indexing (i.e. without constantly doing index arithmetic). To see that, consider what happens if you access `a[1][2]`. After the above loop, `a[1]` contains the value `buffer + 3`, i.e. it points at the *fourth* element of `buffer` (adding `n` to a pointer moves the pointer `n` *elements* forward). So `a[1][2]` is the same as `(buffer+3)[2]` which accesses the value which is two elements further than where `buffer+3` points, in other words, it's equivalent to `buffer[5]`.

More generally, after this initialization `a[i][k]` accesses the same element as `buffer[3*i+k]` (well, unless `i` is larger than 4, of course).

Answer (score 0):

`buffer+i*3;` is just a roundabout way of doing `&buffer[i*3];`.